# Get value of Asp.net TextBox that's inside an item template using jQuery when text has been changed

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have an Asp.net textbox inside of an item template within a gridview.
I would like to access the textbox using jQuery by class name when the text is changed.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amount Paid">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtAmountPaid" runat="server" TextMode="Number" Text='<%# Eval("Amount_Paid") %>' step="any" value="0" CssClass="className" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.className').on('click', function (event) {
        alert('test');
    });
})
```

I have also tried:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('txtAmountPaid').on('click', function (event) {
        alert('test');
    });
})
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("[id*=txtAmountPaid]").change(function () {
        alert('test');
    });
})
```

Comment: When you examine the HTML Output, you should see the INPUT element and the class name assigned to it. Then use `$('.className').change()` callback. You can access the content with `$('.className').val()` If you need more help, please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: last one was almost there... use $("#txtAmountPaid").  (best to use ID as those are unique... many elements can share a style)  But do inspect the element in the browser to check like Twisty says...  sometimes it'll be a 'name' attribute and no id.

Comment: Try: `$('.className').on('input',function(e){ alert('Changed!') });` if not work what you see on console ?

Comment: try to get id like `$('#<%= txtAmountPaid.ClientID %>').click(function () { alert('test'); });`